# Can we avoid the Farm administrators from accessing confidential data of SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, permissions, farm-admin, compliance-center

We have SharePoint 2013 Farm where we have most of the confidential data stored.We are managing the document sharing the with normal business users with proper access management.But as the FARM administrators are having full rights across the farm they can access any document.

So my question is Can we avoid the Farm administrators from accessing confidential data of SharePoint?or there is any auditing process we can place for FARM admins to avoid this access.

Comment: SP Farm administrators have better things to do than read random documents on your site.  If yours don't, you need to find different administrators for your farm.

Answer (score 3):

it is near to impossible to stop them to access the any site in the farm. There are couple of things you can try.

- Dont add them into the Policy of the Web Application, if Farm admins are not in the policy of Web Application then it is hard to get the site collection with their ID.
- enable the auditing on the site collection level, so that you know who is accessing the data. this is the best bet.
- try to monitor the SharePoint auditing logs from server and see if someone try to add into the Policy of web application or site collection admin.

Comment: Using policies can block admins from accessing data via powershell or content DB directly? And what about backups?

Answer (score 0):

Waqas Sarwar has answered this one well, I will add that you should ask the question of why are you trying to restrict Farm admin access. If you cannot trust your admins then you have other problems that you have to address, anyone with that level of access can always find a way around security blocks, through other domain accounts or other ways.

Comment: Farm is handled by third party team....so we need to restrict them.